# looking for a word meaning "not liking and also not hate"

Tags: word-request

I saw a word meaning "not liking and also not hate" but I can't remember it.

> I don't like it but doesn't mean I hate it. I ___ it.

What's the verb or noun I could use for it?

Comment: I can't think of a single word. _I'm indifferent to it_?

Comment: @KateBunting Indifferent is one of those I'm looking for, thanks. but I don't think that's what I'm exactly looking for. It doesn't seem familiar :(

Comment: Also, I am ambivalent towards it, or I tolerate it.

Comment: “I’m undecided.” would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the word **[neutral](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/neutral)** will fill your needs.

> I am **neutral** about it